# NFS server refuses connection when request performed from VM

Tags: networking, nfs, minikube

I guess this is a typical networking issue but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

- I set up an NFS server to accept connections from everywhere: `/test *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`
- I allowed NFS connection in the ufw: `ufw allow nfs`
- I checked that I can mount on my computer: `mount -t nfs <server_IP>:/test`. It works.

But when I try to run the same command in a VM (created by minikube), the command timeouts. Why???
Within the VM I checked that:

- I can ping the NFS server
- I can curl port 2049 (I get err 56 but at least I know that the request passed the firewall).

Here is the list of commands I ran as root:

```
mkdir -p /test
chown nobody:nogroup /test
chmod 777 /test
echo "/test *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)" >> /etc/exports
exportfs -a
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
ufw allow nfs
minikube start
minikube ssh mkdir -p /myTest && sudo mount -t nfs <myIp>:/test /myTest
```

Comment: Could you list in your post all commands that you have used?

Comment: I updated the question to include them.

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let community know about the usefulness, thanks!

Comment: Sorry but your answer gives a recipe to get NFS-based volumes (which I have not tested), but does not point to why the way I did it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we need to configure NFS as a backend for volumes instead of default host (minikube directory). Type this command to export the NFS share:

```
$ echo "/Users -alldirs -mapall="$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" <minikube-ip>"| sudo tee -a /etc/exports
```

Where `minikube-ip` you need to swap with your actual IP address, which you can check by typing following command:

```
$ minikube ip
```

Then, we need to define yaml file to create NFS volume.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  nfs:
    server: <minikube-ip>
    path: /Users/Shared/Sites/
```

We can see that it has created Volume using NFS path which we heave exported before.

```
$ kubectl get pv -o wide
NAME       CAPACITY  ACCESS MODES  RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
test-nfs   8Gi       RWX           Retain           Available             standard                 7s   

$ kubectl describe pv test-nfs
Name:            test-nfs
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     <none>
StorageClass:    standard
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWX
Capacity:        8Gi
Message:
Source:
    Type:      NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:    <minikube-ip>
    Path:      /Users/Shared/Sites/
    ReadOnly:  false
Events:        <none>
```

I encourage you to read [this article](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-volumes-example-nfs-persistent-volume.html) which explains when we should use NFS. I hope it will helps you.